# Submit a form to external sever by keeping header and footer

Tags: php, jquery, forms, iframe, form-submit

In a project I need to submit a form to an external sever using `<form action="post" action="Url to external page">`. But I would like to keep my sites environment there like header,footer etc. Is it possible without using iframes ?  If no, is it possible to access parent php variables with their values in iframe ? Then how can I do that ? Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you any code to show? Have you tried anything? Can your teacher help?

Comment: I would go with iframe, if the iframe is in the same domain of the parent you can access the parent (and viceversa)

Comment: Sounds like you need to use AJAX, however depending on how the target server is configured, you may need to deal with the issues associated with cross-domain requests if you need to work with data returned from the server in javascript. If you can't get cross-domain AJAX to work for wahtever reason, you can also think about making AJAX request to script on your server which can proxy the call to the remote server for you. To me, all of this would be preferable to an iframe solution in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as i see you have to use and Ajax, and there's no other option. Just send an ajax request and process with the returned data. This way you can contact that form without even reloading your page